# How to conditionally modify react-orgchart's orgChart CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm making an organization chart that has collapsible nodes functionalities. These are the CSS classes that control the lines in the chart connecting the nodes:

```
#orgChart .orgNodeChildGroup .nodeGroupLineVerticalMiddle {
    border-right: solid 3px blue;
}
  
#orgChart .nodeLineBorderTop {
    border-top: solid 3px red;
}
```

However, when I collapse a node, I want the lines between the collapsed nodes to disappear, essentially looking like this in CSS:

```
#orgChart .orgNodeChildGroup .nodeGroupLineVerticalMiddle {
    display: none;
}
  
#orgChart .nodeLineBorderTop {
    display: none;
}
```

My App.js:

```
    return (
        <div className="App" id="orgChart">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1><b>Organization Chart</b></h1>
                <h5><i>Click on an box to collapse or uncollapse its children!</i></h5>
            </header>
            <OrgChart tree={orgChartData}
            NodeComponent={node => (
                <EmployeeNode
                    node={node}
                    onToggleCollapse={handleToggleCollapse}
                />
            )}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Apparently, due to the way react-orgchart's OrgChart component is setup, it appears if I want to modify the chart lines, I can only do so in these classes:

```
#orgChart .orgNodeChildGroup .nodeGroupLineVerticalMiddle {
    border-right: solid 3px blue;
}
  
#orgChart .nodeLineBorderTop {
    border-top: solid 3px red;
}
```

Adding extra CSS classes or whatever doesn't work.

Lastly, react-orgchart's apparently has a "collapsible" prop, but there's practically 0 documentation on how to actually use and do it. Hilarious :/

In other words, is there another way to do something like this (just a proof-of-concept of course):

```
#orgChart .orgNodeChildGroup .nodeGroupLineVerticalMiddle (arg_on) {
    if arg_on:
         border-right: solid 3px blue;
    else:
         display: none;
}
```

??